# Using JOIN statement with CONTAINS function

Tags: sql-server, join, contains, sql-like

In SQL Server database I have a View with a lot of INNER JOINs statements. The last join uses LIKE predicate and that's why it's working too slowly. The query looks like :

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN
B ON A.ID = B.ID INNER JOIN
C ON C.ID1 = B.ID1 INNER JOIN
...........................
X ON X.Name LIKE '%' + W.Name  + '%' AND
            LIKE '%' + W.Name2  + '%' AND
            LIKE '%' + W.Name3  + '%'
```

I want to use CONTAINS instead of LIKE as :

```
SELECT *
FROM A INNER JOIN
B ON A.ID = B.ID INNER JOIN
C ON C.ID1 = B.ID1 INNER JOIN
...........................
X ON CONTAINS(X.Name, W.Name) AND
     CONTAINS(X.Name, W.Name2) AND
     CONTAINS(X.Name, W.Name3)
```

I know that CONTAINS is working faster than LIKE and also that can't use CONTAINS in JOIN statements. 
Is there any workaround in this case or suggestion? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM tableA AS_a INNER JOIN tableB AS b
    ON b.field LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(a.field, '%'));

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not that `CONTAINS` can't be used in joins.

You just can't use columns as a second parameter of `CONTAINS` - see [MSDN - CONTAINS (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx)

```
CONTAINS
( { column_name | ( column_list ) | * } 
  ,'<contains_search_condition>'     
[ , LANGUAGE language_term ]
)
```

However, you can use a variable as a search condition, so you can use a cursor and then get all data you need.
Here is some very rough example:

```
declare @Name nvarchar(max)

declare @Temp_A table(Name nvarchar(max))
declare @Temp_B table(Name nvarchar(max))

--=============================================================================================
insert into @Temp_A (Name)
select 'Test'

insert into @Temp_B (Name)
select 'aaaTestaaa'

--=============================================================================================
-- Query 1 - LIKE
--=============================================================================================
select *
from @Temp_A as A
    inner join @Temp_B as B on B.Name like '%' + A.Name + '%'

--=============================================================================================
-- Query 2 - CONTAINS
--=============================================================================================
declare table_cursor cursor local fast_forward for
    select distinct Name from @Temp_A
open table_cursor
while 1 = 1
begin
    fetch table_cursor into @Name
    if @@fetch_status <> 0 break

    select * from @Temp_B where contains(Name, @Name)
end
close table_cursor
deallocate table_cursor
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm not familiar with cursor. Could you please give me an example, how to use it in my case?

Comment: Added some examples (it's very approximate, though)

Answer (score 6):

`CONCAT` works perfect, I have tested it with PostgreSQL

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_ONE AS a INNER JOIN TABLE_TWO AS b
    ON b.field LIKE CONCAT('%', CONCAT(a.field, '%'));
```

Please refer to similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44485265/6521915)

Comment: I don't know why but this is the only solution that works for me, other solutions for joining ON a substring are not working for some reason. So thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a join using a LIKE..
something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_ONE 
FULL OUTER JOIN TABLE_TWO ON TABLE_ONE.String_Column LIKE '%' + TABLE_TWO.Name + '%'
```

ie - select everything from TABLE_ONE where the string_column is contained in the TABLE_TWO name

Answer (score 0):

In short there isn't a way to do this using CONTAINS, it simply is not allowed in a JOIN like this. 
see: [TSQL - A join using full-text CONTAINS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152783/tsql-a-join-using-full-text-contains)

So although there is performance hit, IMO like is the easiest solution here.