# Full-Text Search - How to change the declared variable to a phrase

Tags: sql, full-text-search, sql-server-2014

So I am doing a FTS (Full-Text Search) on names and surnames, the issue comes in when I use spaces in either one of them.

So I have learned that using the `""` inside the single quotes works. But the way I am getting these names is through a select statement and I don't know how to change that variable with the names in them to a phrase

```
select @fName = FirstName, @lName = LastName from Person where ....
```

`@fName` for example is John James and by doing this `'"John James"'` it works, but how do I do it with the above statement ?

Comment: Recommend reviewing my answer on this post as it's a very similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71265906/full-text-search-sql-server-with-parameter/71272497#71272497

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the issue by using Concat as the following

```
    select @LastNamePhrase =  Concat('"',@LastName,'"')

    print @LastNamePhrase

    SELECT * FROM Person WHERE (CONTAINS((Surname), @LastNamePhrase))
```

So with this method I can do the FTS (ignore the print)

Answer (score 0):

You simply can use string concatenation in select statement:

```
select @fName = '"'+FirstName+'"', @lName = LastName from Person where ....
```